# All Authenticated Users claim

Tags: powershell, claims-based-auth, roles

I'm adding items to my list by powershell script. I need to fine-grain user permissions to added items.

Code I'm using now:

```
$claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -ClaimValue $role -ClaimType $ROLE_CLAIM -TrustedIdentityTokenIssuer $sts
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment] $roleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($claim.ToEncodedString(), "", $role, "")
    $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($web.RoleDefinitions[$permissionLevel[$permission]])
    $item.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
    $item.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
    $item.Update()
```

This works when I'm assigning Full Control to administrators. But I'd like also other users to be able to read all items from the list. So I thought I'll add "All Authenticated Users" (like in people picker) read permission. The thing is that I don't what `ClaimValue` and `ClaimType` I have to pass to New-`SPClaimsPrincipal` cmdlet. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the values of $role and $ROLE_CLAIM?

Comment: I don't know either, but if you assign All Users in the browser, can you grab the values in POSH?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get claim for All Authenticated Users in PS you need to use:

```
$claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -EncodedClaim "c:0(.s|true"
```

for windows users (NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users):

```
$claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -EncodedClaim "c:0!.s|windows"
```

and for all forms authenticated users (basic asp.net membership provider)

```
 $claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -EncodedClaim "c:0!.s|forms:aspnetsqlmembershipprovider"
```

After that you can create role assignment like in code you provided and add it to item (I didn't test it myself).

And I still cannot believe that MSDN Forum has nice and simple answer to it [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/3b6ae65b-6b9d-4e4d-8c41-bda19b6b16e1).